# How do I return the collection that are stored inside the database of CosmosDB using nodejs

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-devops, azure-sql-database, azure-cosmosdb

Good afternoon, I am kind of new to using Azure. I have created a temporary database with a container of collections.
In my code, I am already connected to the endpoint, primary key, database, and the container. Now, I would like to print the collections stored in the container of the database.

Here is the code

```
const config = require("./config")
const CosmosClient = require('@azure/cosmos').CosmosClient


const endpoint = config.endpoint
const masterKey = config.primaryKey


const client = new CosmosClient({
    endpoint: endpoint,
    auth: {masterKey: masterKey}
})

const HttpStatusCode = { NOTFOUND: 404}

const databaseId = config.database.id;
const containerId = config.container.id;
```

Comment: Do you want to access the document inside the container or the container itself?

Comment: I want to access the document inside the container.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `query().fetchAll()` command to fetch all documents in a container.

```
const client = new CosmosClient({ endpoint: cosmos.endpoint, key: cosmos.key });
const container = client
    .database(cosmos.databaseId)
    .container(cosmos.containerId);

const querySpec = { query: "SELECT * FROM c" };

// read all items in the container
const { resources } = await container.items.query(querySpec).fetchAll();
```

Comment: this looks good. but I was wondering how I can ```console.log(resources)``` since it is a ```await``` async function

Comment: You can wrap your function in async function and then use `then`.